# Calculating returns within SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stock

I have data on stock prices for multiple companies for the last 10 years. I want to be able to query this table to return the annual (calendar year) stock price return for each of these stocks. Note that the same dates for each stock may not exist, so I am trying to dynamically calculate the return using the earliest and latest available date for each stock.

My table looks like this:

```
Date       | Stock    | Price
========== | ======== | =====
2018-01-03 | AAPL     | 200
2018-04-20 | AAPL     | 210
2018-07-10 | AAPL     | 230
2018-10-05 | AAPL     | 250
2018-12-20 | AAPL     | 290
2019-01-06 | AAPL     | 300
2019-06-15 | AAPL     | 280
2019-09-10 | AAPL     | 340
2019-12-28 | AAPL     | 400
2018-01-02 | MSFT     | 80
2018-04-20 | MSFT     | 90
2018-07-10 | MSFT     | 110
2018-10-05 | MSFT     | 100
2018-12-22 | MSFT     | 95
2019-01-10 | MSFT     | 110
2019-04-20 | MSFT     | 105
2019-06-19 | MSFT     | 120
2019-09-11 | MSFT     | 140
2019-12-30 | MSFT     | 150
```

I am looking to grab the earliest and latest stock price for each stock, as follows:

```
Date       | Stock    | Price
========== | ======== | =====
2018-01-03 | AAPL     | 200
2018-12-20 | AAPL     | 290
2019-01-06 | AAPL     | 300
2019-12-28 | AAPL     | 400
2018-01-02 | MSFT     | 80
2018-12-22 | MSFT     | 95
2019-01-10 | MSFT     | 110
2019-12-30 | MSFT     | 150
```

And finally, I am trying to calculate the return (End of year price / Start of year price - 1)

```
Year  | Stock    | Return
===== | ======== | =====
2018  | AAPL     | 0.45
2019  | AAPL     | 0.3333
2018  | MSFT     | 0.1875
2019  | MSFT     | 0.3636
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this result (as I will be running this on over 1000 stocks in a 10 year period, which is likely to get computationally intensive)?

Comment: use `row_number partition by (year, stock)` to get 1st result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be too bad. I have built this query based on your sample (plus a single row for 2017):

```
DECLARE @stocks TABLE (
    Date    DATETIME,
    Stock   VARCHAR(10),
    Price   MONEY
)

INSERT INTO  @stocks ( Date, Stock, Price )
VALUES
(' 2017-01-03' , 'AAPL', 200),
(' 2018-01-03' , 'AAPL', 200),
(' 2018-04-20' , 'AAPL', 210),
(' 2018-07-10' , 'AAPL', 230),
(' 2018-10-05' , 'AAPL', 250),
(' 2018-12-20' , 'AAPL', 290),
(' 2019-01-06' , 'AAPL', 300),
(' 2019-06-15' , 'AAPL', 280),
(' 2019-09-10' , 'AAPL', 340),
(' 2019-12-28' , 'AAPL', 400),
(' 2018-01-02' , 'MSFT', 80 ),
(' 2018-04-20' , 'MSFT', 90 ),
(' 2018-07-10' , 'MSFT', 110),
(' 2018-10-05' , 'MSFT', 100),
(' 2018-12-22' , 'MSFT', 95 ),
(' 2019-01-10' , 'MSFT', 110),
(' 2019-04-20' , 'MSFT', 105),
(' 2019-06-19' , 'MSFT', 120),
(' 2019-09-11' , 'MSFT', 140),
(' 2019-12-30' , 'MSFT', 150)

SELECT S1.Stock, S1.MinDate, S2.Price, S1.MaxDate, S3.Price
, (S3.Price / S2.Price) - 1 AS 'Return'
FROM (
    SELECT Stock, MIN(date) AS MinDate, MAX(date) AS MaxDate FROM @stocks GROUP BY Stock, YEAR(date)
) AS S1

LEFT JOIN @stocks AS S2
ON S2.Stock = S1.Stock
AND S2.Date = S1.MinDate

LEFT JOIN @stocks AS S3
ON S3.Stock = S1.Stock
AND S3.Date = S1.MaxDate

ORDER BY S1.Stock, YEAR(S1.MinDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Whereas,you have data for the last 10 years then you can try more fast query using `window function` (min,max). Window Functions calculate an aggregate value based on a group of rows and return multiple rows for each group. At first, get the max and min date using `window function`, then using `WHERE` filtering values and at last just get corresponding price for this values using `aggregate function` (and don't need to use distinct):

```
--just get Price corresponding to min/max date grouping by Year,Stock
select Year,Stock,  max(case when Date=max_date then Price end)/max(case when Date=min_date then Price end)-1 as [Return] from 
    (
    --get the MIN and MAX date partition by Year,Stock
    select *,min(Date)over(partition by Stock,datepart(yyyy,Date))min_date,
max(Date)over(partition by Stock,datepart(yyyy,Date))max_date,
    datepart(yyyy,Date)Year from Table
    )X
   where min_date=Date or Date=max_date
   group by Stock,Year
```

Answer (score 1):

A fun way to do this without subqueries is:

```
select distinct stock, year(date),
       first_value(price) over (partition by stock, year(date) order by date) as first_price,
       first_value(price) over (partition by stock, year(date) order by date desc) as last_price,
       (first_value(price) over (partition by stock, year(date) order by date desc) / 
        first_value(price) over (partition by stock, year(date) order by date) - 1
       ) as return
from t;
```

Comment: Cool syntax but when you look at the execution plan, you find out the it is the worst of the 3 proposed solutions by far.

Comment: @emoreau99 . . . You will note that I did not claim that this is the fastest method.

Comment: I like Gordon's solution the best.  It is tight and crisp.